# No Macintosh HD

Tags: macos, software-update, recovery

I was attempting to use an Internet dongle but it wasn't working so I followed some steps online to try and get it to work. I reinstalled El Capitan on to my MacBook but when I returned to recovery mode my Macintosh HD had disappeared. I fear I may have accidentally formatted it in the process and there were no backups in time machine. Now my Mac only turns on in recovery mode and when I try to reinstall the software - I've given up hope on restoring my files - the only drive that is there is a base OS X drive which means there is nowhere to install my software. I'm currently on holiday so can't even take it in the Apple Store so any help would be really appreciated!

Comment: When you go into recovery mode, can you go into Disk Utility and take a screen shot of what you are seeing?

Comment: Has there been an unexpected shutdown or a power failure during the reinstall process? What were the steps you followed and what do you mean by saying "_...but when I returned to recovery mode my Macintosh HD had disappeared._"? After reinstalling OS X you should see the desktop just like regular startup, were you in recovery mode when you tried booting up?

Comment: *"I followed some steps online.... I reinstalled El Capitan..."* How does one logically follow from the other anyway? It's redolent of buying a new car 'cos the ash-tray's full

Comment: In disk utility, does your drive show up at all? Not Macintosh HD, but the physical drive itself

Answer (score 1):

I'll assume you want a step by step guide to erase and install El Capitan.

If so, that is here:

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204904

**Step 6** of the erase section is where you would name **Macintosh HD** as the volume name.